# Wall Street Journal scrape: python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am following up on a very helpful question and response on scraping WSJ news articles (headline + url) using Beautiful Soup in python,
[Getting news from WSJ using BeautifulSoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67384778/getting-news-from-wsj-using-beautifulsoup)

I am trying to modify this to get all articles from the main webpage, https://www.wsj.com/.

My question is that the listed code (below) specifies a specific class to select which articles to scrape. There seem to be many other classes such as `.WSJTheme--bullet-item--5c1Mqfdr` (for enumerated lists) and `style--byline--1k-cTV4i` (for opinion pieces). Is there a way to collect all of these classes to get all of them listed?

Note in my example I could not get the opinion class (the third one) to scrape.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "https://www.wsj.com"
# Specify the `user-agent` in order not to be blocked
header = {
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.93 Safari/537.36"
}

response = requests.get(url, headers=header)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "lxml")

for item in soup.select(".WSJTheme--headline--7VCzo7Ay"):
    # Articles might be under an `h2` or `h3`, use a CSS selector to select both
    headline = item.select_one("h2, h3").get_text()
    link = item.find("a")["href"]
    noticia = headline + " - " + link

    print(noticia)

##bulleted items: `h4' too + note different class
for item in soup.select(".WSJTheme--bullet-item--5c1Mqfdr"):
    headline2 = item.select_one("h4").get_text()
    link2 = item.find("a")["href"]
    noticia2 = headline2 + " - " + link2

    print(noticia2)

##opinion articles --> note different class
for item in soup.select(".style--byline--1k-cTV4i"):
    headline3 = item.select_one("h3").get_text()
    link3 = item.find("a")["href"]
    noticia3 = headline3 + " - " + link3

    print(noticia3)
```

Comment: This is your friendly reminder that your scraper should be honoring [robots.txt](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.robotparser.html).

Comment: Coupled with your friendly reminder that if you redistribute this scraped data, you are committing copyright infringement

Comment: This only gets headlines and urls, not text of the story. As I understand it this fair use. I would not be redistributing this in any way as well, it is for research purposes.

And glad to add a ```robotparser```

Comment: As we are at friendly reminders hour, here's another one: if you find that answer you've inspired from helpful, you should consider upvoting it.

Comment: Thanks I tried that before but my reputation is too low to get an upvote. I di click a thumbs up though on the post and answer I referenced.